# how to call css class from code behind in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have link for a button but when a certain user is logged in I want this link to be hidden.

```
<a href="Stock.aspx" target="_blank" title="Add new Part..." class="btnNewAddress" runat="server" id="btnNewLookup" style="float:right;"></a>
```

I tried changing the style and visibility of the link but it is still displayed.

```
 if (CurrentUser.userType == CurrentUser.User.UserType.MemberUser)
 {
       btnNewLookup.Style.Add("display", "none");
       btnNewLookup.Visible = false;
 }
```

I think the css code is preventing me from changing it. So I wanted to try change the css code from the class. But the class is in a separate css file.

css code:

```
.btnNewAddress {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("../images/icons/buttons/basic1-004-small-invert.png") !important;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  border: 0 solid !important;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}
```

My question is how do I call this css class and change the line `display:block` to `display:none` only when the certain user is logged in?

The link is calling the class `class="btnNewAddress"` and the issue is with the line `display:block`. How do I change this line in the class?

Comment: Why can't you put that CSS code in the CSS file? Are you using Web Forms or MVC? The CSS file will usually be declared in a Master Page (in Web Forms) or a Shared Page (in MVC), so whichever master/shared page your page is using is the CSS file you should add your CSS to. Alternatively you could use developer tools to see where the buttons CSS is coming from.

Comment: btnNewLookup.Attributes.Add( "class", "btnNewAddress " ) also did you put a break point at if block? are you sure your condition is coming as true?

Comment: btnNewLookup.Attributes.Add( "style", "display:block; " )

Comment: @sringland sorry if question is unclear. CSS code is in CSS file.

Comment: @SatyakiChatterjee `btnNewLookup` is already calling css class. The problem is I want to change the `display:block` in the css class. Yes condition is true

Comment: @CMedina changing the style of `btnNewLookup` doesn't hide the link

Comment: if you need show/hide the button from vb code ... btnNewLookup.Style["visibility"] = "show" or btnNewLookup.Style["visibility"] = "hidden"

Comment: Oh so you want to entirely change the CSS of that class? What happens when you update the class the button is in within that CSS file? Doesn't it work? If not then use developer tools on your preferred browser to see where the CSS is coming from.

Comment: @CMedina this is ASP.NET and I tried hiding the button already. You can see the code in my question

Comment: @sringland yes if I change the CSS of the class to `display:none` then it will hide the link. But I only want to hide it for certain users. If I update the class then it will be hidden all the time

Comment: ok I understand, you can not modify the CSS, what you could do is rewrite the class with a Literal control .... it's an idea

Comment: @CMedina could you show some code for adding a Literal Control?

Comment: I would add a different class `btnMyButton.Attributes.Add("class", "buttonClass");` within your if statement and if needs be also add `!important` to  the display line.